# SQL Server : convert Datetime2 into time(7)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time, converters

I am trying to compare a `datetime2` with a `time(7)`

I need help converting the `datatime2`.

This is what I've tried:

```
DECLARE @PracticeStartTime time(7)
DECLARE @PracticeEndTime time(7)

SET @PracticeStartTime = (
    SELECT PBH.StartTime
    FROM PracticePractitioner AS PP WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN PracticeBusinessHours AS PBH WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PBH.PracticeId = PP.PracticeId
    WHERE PP.PractitionerId = @PractitionerId
    )
SET @PracticeEndTime = (
    SELECT PBH.EndTime
    FROM PracticePractitioner AS PP WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN PracticeBusinessHours AS PBH WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PBH.PracticeId = PP.PracticeId
    WHERE PP.PractitionerId = @PractitionerId
    )

IF (
    (
        CONVERT(@ScheduledStart AS TIME) BETWEEN @PracticeStartTime
            AND @PracticeEndTime
        )
    AND (
        CONVERT(@ScheduledEnd AS TIME) BETWEEN @PracticeStartTime
            AND @PracticeEndTime
        )
    )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Time within practice hours';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RETURN - 1
END
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Is this MSSQL?

Comment: @JChao The sql error : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure AppointmentByModalCreate, Line 57
Incorrect syntax near '@ScheduledStart'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is off.

I would use `CAST`

```
cast(@ScheduledStart as time(7))
```

You could use `CONVERT`

```
convert(time(7), @ScheduledStart)
```